# implication rule - semantic equivalence

Tags: logic

If I have

```
(¬q ⇒ r)
```

and use implication on this does it give me:

```
(¬¬q v r)
```

from where I can then use double negation,

or does it give me

```
¬(¬q v r)
```

I am thinking the former.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "use implication on this"? Implication is of course, symbolized by $\implies$.  Are you asking for a logical equivalence to $(\lnot q\implies r)?$

Answer (score 1):

For any two statements $A$ and $B$, the statement $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $(\neg A) \vee B$. In your case, you have the statement $(\neg q) \implies r$, meaning that $\neg q$ takes the place of your $A$. Using the rule then yields $$(\neg(\neg q)) \vee r,$$ or, after using double negation, $q \vee r$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the former:

$$\lnot q \rightarrow r \equiv \lnot(\lnot q)\lor r \equiv q \lor r$$

The equivalences are bi-directional, meaning that from $q\lor r$, we know that $\lnot q \rightarrow r$.